# What is unwrap and unwrap_or in Rust?

Tags: rust, error-handling

> **Note:** The specifics in this question regarding `read_line` and `~str` pertain to a pre-1.0 version of Rust. The general concepts about `unwrap` and `unwrap_or` remain relevant.

I encountered this while reading [*Rust for Rubyists*](https://web.archive.org/web/20190822021204/http://www.rustforrubyists.com/book/book.html):

```rs
let mut reader = BufferedReader::new(io::stdin());
let input = reader.read_line().unwrap_or(~"nothing");
```

Sometimes it's `unwrap`, sometimes it's `unwrap_or`. What is `unwrap` and `unwrap_or`?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> *Note* The specifics in this answer regarding `read_line` and `~str` pertain to a pre-1.0 version of Rust. The general concepts about `unwrap` and `unwrap_or` remain relevant.

Because `read_line` might fail it returns `Option<~str>`. To get the value out you can use pattern matching or one of the unwrap methods.

The difference between `unwrap` and `unwrap_or` is that `unwrap` will fail if there is no value (`None`) but `unwrap_or` will return the specified default ("nothing" in this case)

Answer (score 84):

> *Note* The specifics in this answer regarding `read_line` and `~str` pertain to a pre-1.0 version of Rust. The general concepts about `unwrap` and `unwrap_or` remain relevant.

Rust has API documentation which explains these things.

[`BufferedReader.read_line`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/io/struct.BufferedReader.html#method.read_line):

> ### `fn read_line(&mut self) -> Option<~str>`
>
> > Reads the next line of input, interpreted as a sequence of UTF-8 encoded unicode codepoints. If a newline is encountered, then the newline is contained in the returned string.
> >
> > …
> >
> > [Then something about raising the `io_error` condition, which is one situation in which it would return `None`—if the condition is handled. If it's not it'll fail and so you'll never get anything back.]

You'll also get `None` returned if everything has been read in the reader.

---

[`Option.unwrap`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap):

> ### `fn unwrap(self) -> T`
>
> > Moves a value out of an option type and returns it.
> >
> > Useful primarily for getting strings, vectors and unique pointers out of option types without copying them.
> >
> > …

That is,

- `Some(a).unwrap()` returns `a`
- `None.unwrap()` fails

---

[`Option.unwrap_or`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or):

> ### `fn unwrap_or(self, def: T) -> T`
>
> > Returns the contained value or a default

That is,

- `Some(a).unwrap_or(b)` returns `a`
- `None.unwrap_or(b)` returns `b`

Comment: A handled io_error is not the only situation where you would see None returned from read_line: I am pretty sure it also returns None when the input has hit the EOF (end of file), without signalling a condition.  (I do like your concrete redex style explanations for the Option methods: I will look into adding that to the docs)

Comment: @pnkfelix: you're right. I thought about that but for some reason didn't write it down. Corrected.