# Should I avoid unwrap in production application?

Tags: error-handling, rust

It's easy to crash at runtime with `unwrap`:

```
fn main() {
    c().unwrap();
}

fn c() -> Option<i64> {
    None
}
```

Result:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (file:///playground)
 Running `target/debug/playground`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', ../src/libcore/option.rs:325
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
error: Process didn't exit successfully: `target/debug/playground` (exit code: 101)
```

Is `unwrap` only designed for quick tests and proofs-of-concept?

I can not affirm "My program will not crash here, so I can use `unwrap`" if I really want to avoid `panic!` at runtime, and I think avoiding `panic!` is what we want in a production application.

In other words, can I say my program is reliable if I use `unwrap`? Or must I avoid `unwrap` even if the case seems simple?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36362163/978690) answer:

> It is best used when you are positively sure that you don't have an error.

But I don't think I can be "positively sure".

I don't think this is an opinion question, but a question about Rust core and programming.

Comment: *Crash* is a horribly misused word nowadays IMO; people even use it for an unhandled exception in languages with exceptions. Panicking the program is nowhere near as bad as a segfault, for example. Panicking is deliberately saying "the state of the program is *wrong* and I'm stopping right now, no two ways about it.

Comment: @Shepmaster Ok thanks for these precisions!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

While the whole “error handling”-topic is very complicated and often opinion based, this question can actually be answered here, because Rust has rather narrow philosophy. That is:

- `panic!` for **programming errors** (“bugs”)
- proper error propagation and handling with `Result<T, E>` and `Option<T>` for **expected and *recoverable* errors**

One can think of `unwrap()` as *converting* between those two kinds of errors (it is converting a recoverable error into a `panic!()`). When you write `unwrap()` in your program, you are saying:

> At this point, a `None`/`Err(_)` value is a *programming error* and the program is unable to recover from it.

---

For example, say you are working with a `HashMap` and want to insert a value which you may want to mutate later:

```
age_map.insert("peter", 21);
// ...

if /* some condition */ {
    *age_map.get_mut("peter").unwrap() += 1;
}
```

Here we use the `unwrap()`, because we can be sure that the key holds a value. It would be a programming error if it didn't and even more important: it's not really recoverable. What would you do when at that point there is no value with the key `"peter"`? Try inserting it again ... ?

But as you may know, there is a beautiful [`entry` API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) for the maps in Rust's standard library. With that API you can avoid all those `unwrap()`s. And this applies to pretty much all situations: **you can very often restructure your code to avoid the `unwrap()`**! Only in a very few situation there is no way around it. But then it's OK to use it, if you want to signal: at this point, it would be a programming bug.

---

There has been a recent, fairly popular blog post on the topic of “error handling” whose conclusion is similar to Rust's philosophy. It's rather long but worth reading: [“The Error Model”](http://joeduffyblog.com/2016/02/07/the-error-model/). Here is my try on summarizing the article in relation to this question:

- deliberately distinguish between *programming bugs* and *recoverable errors*
- use a “fail fast” approach for programming bugs

**In summary**: use `unwrap()` when you are sure that the *recoverable* error that you get is in fact *unrecoverable* at that point. Bonus points for explaining *“why?”* in a comment above the affected line ;-)

Comment: Boom, super clear! I read it carefully and learned a lot! I will keep this in mind: "you can very often restructure your code to avoid the unwrap()!"

Comment: I'd +1 that answer if it had just one mention of `expect()`.

Comment: I'd rather he used `expect("")` stating what he was expecting in the string rather than `unwrap()` stating what the was expecting in a comment above!

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Sure, often `expect("")` is a better choice. But: the user should never see panics anyway. And if the stack trace is already enough for the developer to figure out what the problem is, then it's often enough to simply `unwrap()`. Also: I'm talking about 4 to 15 lines comments describing exactly why the following `unwrap()` can't possibly fail. I don't want to type that into a string.

Comment: I prefer something like `.expect("string literal is valid regex")` over `.unwrap()` because it helps to document *why* unwrapping was chosen originally, which can be important for deciding on the proper fix when multiple cycles of maintenance and refactoring have obscured it. (Not to mention possibly informing the reafactoring so the odds of a problem being introduced are lower.)

Answer (score 5):

> In other words, can I say my program is reliable if I use unwrap? Or must I avoid unwrap even if the case seems simple?

I think using `unwrap` judiciously is something you have to learn to handle, it can't just be avoided.

My rhetorical question barrage would be:

1. Can I say my program is reliable if I use indexing on vectors, arrays or slices?
2. Can I say my program is reliable if I use integer division?
3. Can I say my program is reliable if I add numbers?

(1) is like unwrap, indexing panics if you make a *contract violation* and try to index out of bounds. This would be a bug in the program, but it doesn't catch as much attention as a call to `unwrap`.

(2) is like unwrap, integer division panics if the divisor is zero.

(3) is unlike unwrap, addition does not check for overflow in release builds, so it may silently result in wraparound and logical errors.

Of course, there are strategies for handling all of these without leaving panicky cases in the code, but many programs simply use for example bounds checking as it is.

Answer (score 5):

There are two questions folded into one here:

- is the use of `panic!` acceptable in production
- is the use of `unwrap` acceptable in production

`panic!` is a tool that is used, in Rust, to signal irrecoverable situations/violated assumptions. It can be used to either crash a program that cannot possibly continue in the face of this failure (for example, OOM situation) or to work around the compiler knowing it cannot be executed (at the moment).

`unwrap` is a convenience, that is best avoided in production. The problem about `unwrap` is that it does not state which assumption was violated, it is better instead to use `expect("")` which is functionally equivalent but will also give a clue as to what went wrong (without opening the source code).

Answer (score 2):

`unwrap()` is not necessarily dangerous. Just like with `unreachable!()` there are cases where you can be sure some condition will not be triggered.

Functions returning `Option` or `Result` are sometimes just suited to a wider range of conditions, but due to how your program is structured those cases might never occur.

For example: when you create an iterator from a `Vec`tor you buid yourself, you know its exact length and can be sure how long invoking `next()` on it returns a `Some<T>` (and you can safely `unwrap()` it).

Comment: I personally think `unwrap()` is dangerous and prevents your code from modification because it needs you to be very careful when editing the code because `unwrap()` depends on what is written before. Also, you may know some conditions under which some `unwrap()` may be safe but you *must* think that these conditions may change some day and that you will need to reread and understand everything that is done before this unwrap. I also think that if you has already written `unwrap()` it is better to make a comment `// safe` in these lines. I do this to check how much unwrap do I have with `grep`.

Comment: Those conditions may or may not have to change in the future. I'm not saying it's a rule - it's just perfectly possible.

Answer (score -1):

unwrap is great for prototyping, but not safe for production. Once you are done with your initial design you go back and replace `unwrap()` with `Result<Value, ErrorType>`.

Comment: `unwrap` is perfectly *safe* for production. A process that isn't running is in the safest possible state.

Comment: Crash the controller on your airplane and try to call that safe :D