# How can I allow my program to continue when a regex doesn't match?

Tags: regex, rust

I want to use the `regex` crate and capture numbers from a string.

```
let input = "abcd123efg";
let re = Regex::new(r"([0-9]+)").unwrap();
let cap = re.captures(e).unwrap().get(1).unwrap().as_str();
println!("{}", cap);
```

It worked if numbers exist in `input`, but if numbers don't exist in `input` I get the following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value'
```

I want my program continue if the regex doesn't match. How can I handle this error?

Comment: Note: in real code, you should get used to using `expect("what was expected")` rather than `unwrap`, it makes unexpected issues more easily recognizable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably want to (re-)read [the chapter on "Error Handling" in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html). Error handling in Rust is mostly done via the types `Result<T, E>` and `Option<T>`, both representing an optional value of type `T` with `Result<T, E>` carrying additional information about the absence of the main value.

You are calling `unwrap()` on each `Option` or `Result` you encounter. `unwrap()` is a method saying: "if there is no value of type `T`, let the program explode (panic)". [You only want to call `unwrap()` if an absence of a value is *not* expected and thus would be a bug!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477684/should-i-avoid-unwrap-in-production-application/39478185#39478185) (NB: actually, the `unwrap()` in your second line is a perfectly reasonable use!)

But you use `unwrap()` incorrectly twice: on the result of `captures()` and on the result of `get(1)`. Let's tackle `captures()` first; it returns an `Option<_>` and [the docs say](https://docs.rs/regex/0.2.1/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.captures):

> If no match is found, then `None` is returned.

In most cases, the input string not matching the regex is to be expected, thus we should deal with it. We could *either* just `match` the `Option` (the standard way to deal with those possible errors, see the Rust book chapter) *or* we could use [`Regex::is_match()`](https://docs.rs/regex/0.2.1/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.is_match) before, to check if the string matches.

Next up: `get(1)`. Again, [the docs tell us](https://docs.rs/regex/0.2.1/regex/struct.Captures.html#method.get):

> Returns the match associated with the capture group at index `i`. If `i` does not correspond to a capture group, or if the capture group did not participate in the match, then `None` is returned.

But this time, we don't have to deal with that. Why? Our regex (`([0-9]+)`) is constant and we know that the capture group exists and encloses the whole regex. Thus we can rule out both possible situations that would lead to a `None`. This means we can `unwrap()`, because we don't expect the absence of a value.

The resulting code could look like this:

```
let input = "abcd123efg";
let re = Regex::new(r"([0-9]+)").unwrap();
match re.captures(e) {
    Some(caps) => {
        let cap = caps.get(1).unwrap().as_str();
        println!("{}", cap);
    }
    None => {
        // The regex did not match. Deal with it here!
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `is_match` here is specifically recommended against: *"It is recommended to use this method if **all you need to do is test a match**"* (emphasis mine) — Using `is_match` combined with `captures` causes the regex to be evaluated twice, adding inefficiency.

Answer (score 1):

You can either check with [`is_match`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.6/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.is_match) or just use the return type of `captures(e)` to check it (it's an [`Option<Captures<'t>>`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.6/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.captures)) instead of unwrapping it, by using a `match` (see [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/) how to handle options).