# Parse integer or provide default value with unwrap_or, but print error message when default value is used

Tags: rust

I have written some code that parses a config file. If the config file holds a valid value for a field it sets in `Config` struct. If no valid integer value was found for a setting it sets a default value (e.g: 90).

```
let config = Config {
    interval: settings.get("interval").unwrap().parse().unwrap_or(90),
}
```

How can I make this to take a closure, so that it can print via `error!` and set default value?

Looking something like following:

```
let config = Config {
    interval: settings.get("interval").unwrap().parse().unwrap_or({
        error!("No interval found. Using default: 90");
        90
    });
}
```

But in this example, the `error!` is always executed, even if a valid value from interval was read from the config.

How can I make it so that unwrap_or only executes the code in `optb` when `parse()` has failed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I make it so that `unwrap_or` only executes the code in `optb` when `parse()` has failed?

- Arguments passed to `unwrap_or` are ***eagerly evaluated***.
- If you are passing the result of a function call, it is recommended
  to use `unwrap_or_else` which is ***lazily evaluated***.

In your scenario it should be changed as following:

```
let config: Config = Config {
   interval: settings.get("interval").unwrap().parse().unwrap_or_else(|_| {
        error!("No interval found. Using default: 90");
        90
    }),
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=06932df6fa0d63e582aa640797a70187)

---

Also you should not use naked `unwrap()` in your production code. 
Error handling is better solution instead of using naked `unwrap()`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477684/should-i-avoid-unwrap-in-production-application) you can find detailed info about why you should not use `unwrap()`

Comment: Ahh, easy enough. This was what i was looking for. I'll read up on the differences between the _or() and _or_else() functions. I suspect the _ in this will be the error on which the parse failed?

Comment: Yes exactly,  To keep the answer minimal, I did not handle the error in the answer, just silenced it with underscore

Comment: The issue of `unwrap()` is a bit more nuanced than "don't panic in production". The answers to the linked question are a pretty good starting point. I'd guess that @Robin may want to treat the absence of an `"interval"` field the same way as an unparseable value, in which case one way to do that would be `.and_then(|value| value.parse().ok())` instead of `.unwrap().parse()`.