# Borrow a value wrapped in an Option using a method

Tags: rust

I would like to write a method on a struct which borrows a value wrapped in an `Option` in one of its properties/fields.

Is it doable ?

Consider

```
struct A {}

struct Obj {
    a: Option<A>
}

impl Obj {
    fn ref_to_a(&self) -> &A {
        //&self.a.unwrap() <-- How do I implement this ?
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ff1b68b8f5418e93aae2d91b0d13c672)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are not borrowing `Option` itself, but you can mimic `unwrap` behavior by this way :

```
impl Obj {
    fn ref_to_a(&self) -> &A {
        match self.a {
            Some(ref a) => return a,
            None => panic!("There is no value"),
        }
    }
}
```

**Note :**
[Should I avoid unwrap in production application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477684/should-i-avoid-unwrap-in-production-application)

Comment: Ahhh `Some(ref a)`. Thanks. (I am not borrowing the Option directly due to the way I chain functions and handle errors down the line; I do not use `unwrap`, this is a very simplified example of my use case).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) to *"Convert from `Option<T>` to `Option<&T>`."*

```rust
impl Obj {
    fn ref_to_a(&self) -> &A {
        self.a.as_ref().unwrap()
    }
}
```

Of course you shouldn't use `unwrap`, but at least `expect`.

Comment: Thanks; I actually ended up using `as_ref`. @Ömer Erden answer put me on that path. (for `unwrap`, sure, see my comment above)

Comment: Is there any compiler optimization for using multiple match in here ? `as_ref` uses matching and `unwrap`(`expect`) also does, otherwise there would be unnecessary check.

Comment: @ÖmerErden https://godbolt.org/z/WPx_Ep