# How to repeatedly call function until it returns Some and avoid .unwrap()?

Tags: rust

I'm building a toy compiler and have the following code:

```rust
pub fn next_token(&mut self) -> Token {
    let mut token_option = self.get_longest_match();

    while let None = token_option {
        token_option = self.get_longest_match();
    }

    let token = token_option.unwrap();

    token
}
```

`get_longest_match` returns an `Option<Token>`, which may be `None` if we are hitting whitespace (I also recognize this isn't a great way of handling this, but that's less the point of this question). So then we loop until we hit something that is not `None` (which includes an EOF token) and then unwrap it and return it. The biggest question for me is this `unwrap` call. It seems like everywhere I can find online considers unwrapping without special handling for a `None` value bad, but in this case it should not be able to be `None`.

So is this unwrap something people would see in production normally or is there a better way to go about this in Rust?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477684/should-i-avoid-unwrap-in-production-application; I don't know how this code can be restructured to avoid `unwrap` (I guess it's possible).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is fine. That `unwrap` call is ugly, but in cases like these you shouldn't worry too much about it: there are indeed situations where it's impossible to express that a particular value is provably `Some(_)`. In production code, you should put a comment on there explaining why the `unwrap` call should never panic.

But in this case, you can actually do better:

```
pub fn next_token(&mut self) -> Token {
    loop{
        if let Some(token) = self.get_longest_match() {
            return token;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this can also work if you don't want to return from the function when you find the token: you can break `loop`s with a "return value":

```
pub fn next_token(&mut self) -> Token {
    let token = loop{
        if let Some(token) = self.get_longest_match() {
            break token;
        }
    };

    token
}
```