# A Rust function return a future, after .await(), it may be throw a panic!. How can I avoid the panic! to stop the program?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm making a function `call_data()`, it will return a future. In the main function, I use tokio task to call `call_data()` forever each 60 seconds. Some time, the `call_data()`.await is a Error, so there is a panic! and stop the program. I try `let a = call_data("name", "table").await;`, then use `match`, if `Ok`, future is excuted, if `Error`, continue. However, that is not work, if there is panic!, still throw the panic!.  Do I have any ways to avoid the panic! for this program? Below is the code I do not using match!

```
async fn main() {
    let forever = task::spawn(async {
        let mut interval = interval(Duration::from_millis(60000));
        println!("Start");
        loop {
            interval.tick().await;
            call_data("name", "table").await;
        }
    });
    forever.await;
}

async fn call_data(name:&str, table: &str){
    data().unwrap();
}
```

This is the code I use `match`

```
async fn main() {
        let forever = task::spawn(async {
            let mut interval = interval(Duration::from_millis(60000));
            println!("Start");
            loop {
                let a =call_data("BTC-USD", "test3").await;
                match a{
                      Ok=>(),
                      Err=>continue,
                 }
            }
        });
        forever.await;
    }
    
    async fn call_data(name:&str, table: &str){
        data().unwrap();
    }
```

Comment: `match`-ing on an error (or a similar method) instead of `unwrap()` is the intended way to avoid panics and handle errors gracefully. Why did it not work for you? If you paste the code you tried using `match` and the error you received, people would be able to help you easier.

Comment: @justinas, yes, I update the post. I put the match code inside! Thank s for your suggestion!!!

Comment: As I can see in your code, `call_data` doesn't return `Result`, and panic probably occurs in `call_data` fn, because of `.unwrap()`

Comment: Be sure to read the [documentation for `unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) and maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36362163/574531) that explains what it does. You can't "catch" a `panic!`; you have to avoid creating one in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your fn `call_data` should look something like

```rust
async fn call_data(name: &str, table: &str) -> std::result::Result<Data, Box<dyn error::Error>> {
    Ok(Data {})
}
```

and `match` should look like

```rust
match call_data("", "").await {
    Ok(data) => {
        // do something with data
    },
    Err(e) => println!("Error: {:?}", e),
}
```