# tokio::net::TcpStream how to handle any kind of errors?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I stuck with proper handling panics in case of tokio::net::TcpStream

```
use tokio::*;
use tokio::{net::{ TcpStream }, io::AsyncWriteExt};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("10.20.30.40:6142").await.unwrap();
    println!("created stream");

    let result = stream.write(b"hello world\n").await;
    println!("wrote to stream; success={:?}", result.is_ok());
}
```

or in [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=39be6cd5823ec934c0539975a1b6a71c)

Can guru teach me how to catch these errors like

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err`
> value: Os { code: 101, kind: NetworkUnreachable, message: "Network is
> unreachable" }', src/main.rs:6:67

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is unwrap in Rust, and what is it used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362020/what-is-unwrap-in-rust-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. 
I know what is unwrap yet got confused how to handle this.

Comment: Have you looked at the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36362163/5397009) to the suggested duplicate? It shows how to handle this: specifically don't use `unwrap` and use `match` or `if let` and/or `?`

Comment: of course. Solution is same but question is different. I knew how unwrap works but it was not helping me. My question was about handling TcpStream connections errors. Maybe for you it is obvious but not for me.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, "duplicate" means that the answer is the same even if the question is formulated differently. It doesn't mean that your question would be deleted, on the contrary [duplicate questions are explicitly kept to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to change `main()` to handle errors, and use the `?` operator instead of `unwrap()` to propagate them.

```
type SomeResult<T> = Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> SomeResult<()> {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("10.20.30.40:6142").await?;
    println!("created stream");

    let result = stream.write(b"hello world\n").await;
    println!("wrote to stream; success={:?}", result.is_ok());

    Ok(())
}
```

The last line (`Ok(())`) is because `main()` now expects a result returned. I also added an alias so you can reuse the `SomeResult` for other functions from which you might want to propagate errors. [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f8051246dc6e46cea60c68fd09286519) is a playground.