# How do I connect C# desktop application to an Android app?

Tags: java, c#, .net

I have a [Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) C# application which uses SQL Local DB 2016.
My C# application is being used by some few peoples.
I want to receive data to an Android app from the C# application.
I want to show the records in my Android app from the C# application.

What are the different ways to connect?
What is the preferred way in my case?

I don't know any ways in this case. I have previously developed an online Android app in which I’ve used PHP scripts to send and receive data on the [000webhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostinger) platform.

Answer (score 2):

xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: @DavidW, If you are unsure about my writing, do you want me to delete it?

Comment: @DavidW, he didn't ask for any source code. And, apparently accepted my answer.

Comment: You won't be able to delete an accepted answer. I have no opinion on the quality of this answer, except that a lot of people have posted unvalidated low-quality ChatGPT answers so I'm pretty suspicious of them generally.

Comment: Formatting and writing style is exactly what you get from ChatGPT.

Comment: @Neil: Agreed. It is probably more than just ChatGPT fixing [spelling mistakes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362020/what-is-unwrap-in-rust-and-what-is-it-used-for/76650561#76650561) ([agrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_%28computer_programming%29), [woud](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/would#Verb), and [erro](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/error#Noun)). Though the ChatGPT signals are ***weak*** (increased answer volume and verboseness in answers after [December 2022](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)).