# How to return a reference to a global vector or an internal Option?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a method that can return a reference to `Data` that is either in a constant global array or inside an `Option` in an item. The lifetimes are certainly different, but it's safe to assume that the lifetime of the data is at least as long as the lifetime of the item. While doing this, I expected the compiler to warn if I did anything wrong, but it's instead generating wrong instructions and the program is crashing with `SIGILL`.

Concretely speaking, I have the following code failing in Rust 1.27.2:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Type {
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Data {
    pub ctype: Type,
    pub int: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Entity {
    pub idata: usize,
    pub modifier: Option<Data>,
}

impl Entity {
    pub fn data(&self) -> &Data {
        if self.modifier.is_none() {
            &DATA[self.idata]
        } else {
            self.modifier.as_ref().unwrap()
        }
    }
}

pub const DATA: [Data; 1] = [Data {
    ctype: Type::TYPE2,
    int: 1,
}];

fn main() {
    let mut itemvec = vec![Entity {
        idata: 0,
        modifier: None,
    }];
    eprintln!("vec[0]: {:p} = {:?}", &itemvec[0], itemvec[0]);
    eprintln!("removed item 0");
    let item = itemvec.remove(0);
    eprintln!("item: {:p} = {:?}", &item, item);
    eprintln!("modifier: {:p} = {:?}", &item.modifier, item.modifier);
    eprintln!("DATA: {:p} = {:?}", &DATA[0], DATA[0]);
    let itemdata = item.data();
    eprintln!("itemdata: {:p} = {:?}", itemdata, itemdata);
}
```

[Complete code](https://github.com/lpenz/rust-sigill)

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Why isn't the compiler generating a warning? Is it the removal of the (non-copy) item of the vector? Is it the ambiguous lifetimes?

Comment: You probably want to use `static` instead of `const`. In practice they may be the same, but `static` guarantees the behavior you probably want: that there's only one `DATA` array and all references are to its interior.

Answer (score 4):

> How to return a reference to a global vector or an internal Option?

By using [`Option::unwrap_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else):

```
impl Entity {
    pub fn data(&self) -> &Data {
        self.modifier.as_ref().unwrap_or_else(|| &DATA[self.idata])
    }
}
```

> but it's instead generating wrong instructions and the program is crashing with `SIGILL`

The code in your question does not have this behavior on macOS with Rust 1.27.2 or 1.28.0. On Ubuntu I see an issue when running the program in Valgrind, but the problem goes away in Rust 1.28.0.

See also:

- [Why should I prefer `Option::ok_or_else` instead of `Option::ok_or`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45547293/155423)
- [What is this unwrap thing: sometimes it's unwrap sometimes it's unwrap_or](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21257686/155423)