# How do I get a value instead of Err in Rust?

Tags: rust, unwrap

I'm querying a database and putting the results into a struct.

```
    let mut stmt = conn.prepare("SELECT operator, site, starttime, endtime......");
    let rows = stmt.query_map([], |row| {
        Ok(ti_data {
            operator: row.get(0)?,
            site: row.get(1)?,
            starttime: row.get(2)?,
            endtime: row.get(3)?,
            //more data here
          })
    };
```

Some values will be null and I can't change that since the data is created elsewhere and the code will panic if I try to use elements with null values.
How can I replace null with 0 or ""?

I'm new to Rust and used to be checking values myself in C/C++/C#.

I would like to have something like

```
    if (row.get(i).? == None) {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered `unwrap_or()`. Maybe this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257686/what-is-unwrap-and-unwrap-or-in-rust

Comment: shouldn't you make those fields Option<T> if they can be null?

Comment: What is `\[\]`? That's not any syntax I recognize. I also don't see anything in your code that would panic on null values.

Comment: \[\] came from the posting. It is simply [ ].
But I think unwrap_or will do the trick! Thanks!

Comment: You could try the `match (row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2), ..)` pattern where you can then `(Some(operator), Some(site), Some(starttime), ...))` to catch the case where they're all set. You could also add a function that converts `None` to an `Err` of some sort.

Comment: What should happen if one of the items is null?